# Yii2 OpenId Connect error - yii2-authclient returns 400 error "Token not provided" when I try to getUserAttributes()

Tags: php, yii2, openid-connect, yii2-authclient

I'm implementing OpenId Connect into my Yii2 app using the yii2-authclient library. I can login and exchange the code for a token with no problems. I've followed most of the code examples on the web and set a successCallback function that gets called once a user successfully logs in. It looks like this:

```
public function successCallback(ClientInterface $client) 
{
    $attributes = $client->getUserAttributes();
}
```

This code gets called, but calling `getUserAttributes()` results in the following error:

> Exception – yii\authclient\InvalidResponseException
>   Request failed with code: 400, message:
>       {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Token not provided"}

The logs on the id server show a blank client and user, with an error of `invalid_token`.

I took a close look at the request I make and I see an `access_token` element. Any ideas what the problem might be? I can provide more information if necessary.

Comment: More information: Here's the URL I'm hitting:

`https://id.dev.[url removed].com/auth/realms/terradatum/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo?access_token=eyJhb[rest of token removed]`

and am getting the following response:

`{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Token not provided"}`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was that the yii2-authclient library was sending the token as a GET parameter and the ID server was expecting it as a POST param. I upgraded the yii2-authclient library and that solved the problem since a recent change sends the parameter as POST instead of GET.